# Azure AD Connect ADSync error 0x80230613

Tags: entra-id

I noticed that an Azure AD Connect Password sync was giving *Warning: no recent synchronization*, which was clearly caused by misconfiguration: password synchronization was indeed disabled. Trying to modify settings however failed, Connect to Azure AD claiming that the account wasn't an administrator.

> Please provide administrator credentials for contoso.onmicrosoft.com - AAD.

Double checked that this account has the *Global administrator* role and also tried another account. Trying with a wrong password or an account with a pending forced password change gives another, reasonable error: there's nothing wrong with the connection. Updated from 1.1.561.0 to the latest 1.1.750.0, but that didn't help either.

Both time ADSync gives following event 6306,

```
The server encountered an unexpected error while performing an operation for the client.

"BAIL: MMS(5036): ..\mastate.cpp(8818): 0x80230613 (Operation failed
     because the specified management agent could not be found.)
BAIL: MMS(5036): ..\mastate.cpp(10113): 0x80230613 (Operation failed...
BAIL: MMS(5036): ..\ma.cpp(316): 0x80230613 (Operation failed...
BAIL: MMS(5036): ..\ma.cpp(437): 0x80230613 (Operation failed...
BAIL: MMS(5036): ..\server.cpp(2007): 0x80230613 (Operation failed...
Azure AD Sync 1.1.750.0"
```

followed by .NET Runtime event 1026 and Application Error (event 1000):

```
Faulting application name: Microsoft.Identity.AadConnect.Health.AadSync.Host.exe, 
    version: 3.0.127.0, time stamp: 0x59eb08bc
Faulting module name: RPCRT4.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18939, time stamp: 0x5a7f2493
Exception code: 0xc0000005
```

Should I continue debugging this or simply completely remove the Azure AD Connect and start from scratch? I'm a bit afraid that Azure AD Connect DB could have something extra for matching the local AD accounts with the corresponding Azure AD accounts, possibly leading to duplicated or orphaned accounts on the cloud side. What are the actual risks here?

Comment: Not sure if you raised a support ticket. If you didnt, then you absolutely should.

Comment: @maweeras: Thanks for your reply. I ended up reinstalling & reconfiguring AD Connect, which solved the problem.  I left this open if someone knows an actual reason for the error and a faster way to solve this.